# I can't get the current time of the system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Laravel attendance application**
I use carbon class for getting the current time of the system but I get the time -4h, how can I fix it ;
*My code*

---

**AttendanceController.php**

---

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DateTime;
use App\User;
use App\Latetime;
use App\Attendance;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Requests\AttendanceEmp;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AttendanceController extends Controller
{
public function assign(AttendanceEmp $request)
{
    $request->validated();

    if ($employee = User::whereEmail(request('email'))->first()){
        
        $mytime = Carbon::now();
        if (Hash::check($request->pin_code, $employee->pin_code)) {
                if (!Attendance::whereAttendance_date(date("Y-m-d"))->whereUser_id($employee->id)->first()){
                    $attendance = new Attendance;
                    $attendance->user_id = $employee->id;
                    $attendance->attendance_time = $mytime->toTimeString();
                    $attendance->attendance_date = date("Y-m-d");

                    if (!($employee->schedules->first()->time_in >= $attendance->attendance_time)){
                        $attendance->status = 0;
                    AttendanceController::lateTime($employee);
                    };
                    $attendance->save();

                }else{
                    return redirect()->route('attendance.login')->with('error', 'you assigned your attendance before');
                }
            } else {
            return redirect()->route('attendance.login')->with('error', 'Failed to assign the attendance');
        }
    }



    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Successful in assign the attendance');
}
```

---

Comment: On `config.php` change your timezone `'timezone' => 'UTC',` here is the list http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: it depends on the timezone in your laravel configuration. The one configured is -4h the one of your system

Comment: @sta please can you tell me the where can i find exactly this config.php file ?

Comment: @emmaemma what is your current timezone, or where you are located?

Comment: @sta in uae , but i dont know where the config.php on my application ?

Comment: @emmaemma my bad, it would be `config/app.php` line number 70

Comment: @sta i already have 'timezone' => 'UTC' on my config/app.php

Comment: @emmaemma yeah, you need to change it, like : `'timezone' => 'Europe/Copenhagen',`

Comment: @sta thank you a lot , it work right now ! :)